# !important on makeStyle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display snackbar over dialog.
My dialog have an zIndex of 1500 and it must be that.
My snackbar that is a custom Component that use MaterialUI Snackbar have a zIndex of 1400 automatically and I want to change that but my method doesn't work.

```
const useContentStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    containerRoot :{
        color:'blue !important',
        backgroundColor: 'green !important',
        zIndex: 1501,
    }
}))

const App: FunctionComponent = () => {

return (
        <>
          <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={4} anchorOrigin={{vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center'}} classes={{containerRoot: classes.containerRoot}}>
                <SnackbarConsumer messageType={'error'} time={4000} />
                <SnackbarConsumer messageType={'success'} time={4000} />
                <SnackbarConsumer messageType={'info'} time={4000} />
                <SnackbarConsumer messageType={'warning'} time={4000} />
         </SnackbarProvider>;
       </>
     )
}
```

My zIndex is applied but I must to write !important to make it work but I can't do that:

```
const useContentStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    containerRoot :{
        color:'blue !important',
        backgroundColor: 'green !important',
        zIndex: 1501 !important,
    }
}))
```

What Can I do ?

Comment: what is `SnackbarProvider` and `SnackbarConsumer`? please specify what library you're using, material-ui doesn't have those components

Comment: does `zIndex: '1501 !important'` not work (wrapping the value in a string)? Objects must contain one of the native types for the JS to be processed without an error

Comment: @SteveHynding zIndex: '1501 !important' don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe Template literals could be a solution.

```
const index = 1501;
containerRoot :{
    color:'blue !important',
    backgroundColor: 'green !important',
    zIndex: `${index} !important`
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why it works. You only have defined a variable.. 
Could you explain it better?